# NuGet exclude files from symbols package in nuspec

Tags: nuget, symbols, nuspec

When doing a nuget pack against a .csproj file that has an accompanying .nuspec file, what is the syntax for excluding certain files from the symbols .nupkg?

For clarity, I do not want to exclude these files from the normal .nupkg, just from the symbols .nupkg. This is because SymbolSource [fails to parse these files](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/273#issuecomment-33792336) as managed assemblies.

Our [workaround](https://gist.github.com/grenade/4d248e9ea8f6b5e7636a) is to remove specific files from the symbols .nupkg after it has been created but it would be preferable to exclude them in some declarative fashion in either [the .nuspec file](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/nuget.package/LibGit2Sharp.nuspec) or else in the package command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be abit of hack, but you could something like this:

```
nuget pack mypackage.nuspec -Symbols -Exclude "*/*.exe;*/*.dll"
```

Where `"*/*.exe;*/*.dll"` are the files you want to ignore and then run

```
nuget pack mypackage.nuspec
```

Where your mypackage.nuspec includes everything that you want in your regular nuget package.

This shouldn't cause any problems, since the dll, pdb and nuget packages should still have all matching versions.

Comment: Hack or not, it's the best (only) solution so far. Thanks!